# Index was outside of bounds of the array error

Tags: c#

```
public class dailyMenu          
{               

    private string day="";
    private int date = 0; 
    private static int nextDate=1;
    private string entree ="";
    private double price;
    private double calories;

    private static string [] daysOfWeek= {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
        "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

    private static string[] entrees = {"Beef Tenderloin Fresco", 
        "Madagascar Filet Mignon", "Filet Mignon", " Lobster Ravioli",
        "Asian Infused Braised Beef", "New Age Chicken Cordon Bleu", 
        "Short Ribs", " Beef Wellington","Fajitas", "Bacon Cheeseburger", 
        "Beef Burgandy", "Spagehetti"};

    private static double [] entreePrices= { 5.99,7.99,6.99,4.50,9.99,10.29,
        5.67,8.99, 3.99,4.78,10,79,6.98};

    private static int[] entreeMealCaloricVal= { 999,1288,770,699,450,999,1500,873, 911,
        1011, 777,500}; 

    public dailyMenu()
    {
        assignDate();
        GetDay();
        RandPopulate();
    }

    void assignDate()
    {
        date = nextDate;
        nextDate++;

        if (GetDay()== "Friday") 
        {
            nextDate += 2;
        }
    }

    void RandPopulate()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(0,13);

        entree = entrees [randomNumber];
        price = entreePrices [randomNumber];
        calories = entreeMealCaloricVal [randomNumber];
    }
}
```

The IDE is telling me that line 56, 41, and 14 could be the problem so I'm guessing it has something to do with my random number generator.

Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: What does your `GetDay()` function look like?

Comment: string GetDay()
   {
    return daysOfWeek [(date % 7) - 1];
   }

Comment: Change it to: `string GetDay() { return daysOfWeek [(date % 7)]; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like `entrees` and `entreeMealCaloricVal` contain 12 items.  That means they'll be indexed from 0 to 11.

Using `random.Next(0,13)` will generate a number from 0 to 12.  When you try to access those arrays at index 12, your exception gets thrown.

Comment: He has more than just this. He was also trying to call daysOfWeek[-1] in the GetDay function when the date was a multiple of 7.

Comment: Good call, that method wasn't in the original code he posted though.

Comment: I asked to see it in the comments before counting items in the arrays. You had already answered the main culprit before I had a chance. =)

Comment: Thank you guys so just change the 13 to a 12?

Comment: And fix your getDay function

Comment: And no, changing 13 to 12 is not the best solution. You want to change it to the length of your array. Something like `entrees.Length`. You should also look at creating an object for the data and drop it into one array rather than creating separate arrays.

Comment: Alright I've done that but when i run my code to print it out the day of the week does not show up, but my entree price and calories do.